# How to apply a gamma filter in matlab?

Tags: matlab

So I'm trying to enhance the contrast of my image, and I found one gentleman to be doing it via gamma correction online, with the following code:

```
(im/255).^0.45*255
```

from what I understand, 1/gammavalue = 0.45 where gammavalue depends on the monitor (between 1.0 and 2.2), and we raise the image to the power of 1/.45, but I do not understand why the two operations with '255' are in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the original values that person was working with were between 0 and 255, and gamma correction is often applied on values between 0 and 1. So what the code does is rescale the values to be between 0 and 1, apply the gamma filter, and rescale back to the original range.